# How can I log in to an existing github repo without using github cli

Tags: git, github

I can't believe I'm asking this after using Github for years, but I'd like to know how do I log into Github.

I would like to know if there is a simple process to logging into Github using the new PAT system without having to download Github CLI and running `gh auth login`

Is there any simple, step by step solution that works across Windows, Mac, and Linux?

For context: I use Github to share code across different Windows, Mac, and Linux devices so copy and pasting a PAT or installing Github CLI every time is very tedious (and possibly not secure). Every other guide I've seen online is either very complicated or works only in certain situations. Surely just logging isn't supposed to be this hard?

Comment: To actually use git functionality you need some kind of library / binary to do the work. _or_ you can do what I often do, which is simply work locally and copy/paste directly into the github web portal. You can do a lot through the web portal without requiring Git cmd line.

Comment: What is the actual requirement? _"I use Github to share code across different Windows, Mac, and Linux devices"_ _"Surely just logging isn't supposed to be this hard"_

Answer (score 0):

If you need to enter your credentials (which are now: your Github usser account name, and a PAT/token), you need to make sure to use a [git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) to cache said token.

Check the output of `git config --global crednetial.helper`

On Windows:

| OS | credential helper |
| --- | --- |
| Windows | manager-core |
| Mac | osxkeychain |
| Linux | libsecret |

Note that [`microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core`](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/) could be installed on all three OS and used (as `manager-core`) there.

That way, the first time you push back to a remote GitHub repository, it will ask you for your credentials, and cached them locally: no more PAT to copy everywhere for each Git operation.